# Ambiguous overloaded java methods with generics and varargs

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

I'm trying to understand how java deals with ambiguities in function calls. In the following code, the call to `method` is ambiguous, but `method2` is not!!!.

I feel both are ambiguous, but why does this compile when I comment out the call to `method`? Why is `method2` not ambiguous as well?

```
public class A {
    public static <K> List<K> method(final K arg, final Object... otherArgs) {
        System.out.println("I'm in one");
        return new ArrayList<K>();
    }

    public static <K> List<K> method(final Object... otherArgs) {
        System.out.println("I'm in two");
        return new ArrayList<K>();
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> method2(final K k0, final V v0, final Object... keysAndValues) {
        System.out.println("I'm in one");
        return new HashMap<K,V> ();
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> method2(final Object... keysAndValues) {
        System.out.println("I'm in two");
        return new HashMap<K,V>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> c = A.method2( "ACD", new Integer(4), "DFAD" );
        //List<Integer> d = A.method(1, "2", 3  );
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
This came up in comments: A number of IDEs report both as ambiguous - IntelliJ and Netbeans so far. However, it compiles just fine from command-line/maven.

Comment: Maybe it would increase compilation time if java checked for unused methods

Comment: @Joelmob I feel the question is why does `method2` compile when it seems to be just as ambiguous as `method`.

Comment: @BrianRoach which java are you using ? I'm using 1.6 on MacOSX. Interestingly IntelliJ reports both as ambiguous, but it compiles form the commandline.

Comment: not sure indeed, but i think it has to do with you method 2 has 2 different types of arguments K and V.

Comment: NM, Netbeans says both are ambiguous, but Java doesn't. Odd.

Comment: I think the question should be: "Why is `method2` not ambiguous in this situation".

Comment: @Jivings added explicit question on why `method2` is not ambiguous.

Comment: @esaj: With method or method2? The compile error is with method.

Comment: This is really going to hurt your head but, here's the rules from the spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5 - What I suspect is that with the two generic parameters `method2` can be said to be "strictly more specific" - I leave you to do the math there, I'm at lunch :-D

Comment: @esaj Same Environment here (but Arch Linux) and I get a compilation error in Helios on `A.method`.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler: just noticed that it was only calling method2, my bad =)

Comment: With `javac 1.7.0_02` it doesn't compile, even from command line, `method2` is properly considered ambiguous.

Comment: Interesting that the compilation behavior in Java 7 is different. [The spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) looks similar given a cursory glance.

Comment: Thanks @alain.janinm I think there was a bug in JDK6. Some bugs related to ambiguous invocations have been solved in Java 7, according to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#jdk7. I couldn't find this particular case.

Comment: Probably, moreover according to varargs doc `you should not overload a varargs method, or it will be difficult for programmers to figure out which overloading gets called.` However it's interesting to understand how works the resolution of the "most specific method". If you need some help to understand the spec you can read http://stackoverflow.com/q/6023439/1140748 and also a well explained example https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9485871#9485871.

Comment: Is it even possible to call the second `method2` in this case? For example, `A.method2( "ACD", "ABC", "DFAD" );` still calls the first `method2` whereas `Map<String, Integer> c = A.method2( "ACD", "ABC", "DFAD" );` results in a compile-time error. Seems to me that the first `method2` is the one that is considered, no matter what.

Comment: @VivinPaliath: yes, when you pass only zero or one arguments.

Comment: @dragon66 Oops, I meant when passing in > 1 arguments. You're right with zero or one argument the second `method2` gets called.

Comment: Following the authors of "SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 (Exam 310-065)", we should not rely on IDE errors or warnings when in doubt but rather give credit for javac output command instead. 
Saying this i think that this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361513/reference-is-ambiguous-with-generics that in turn resumes to a bug for oracle at http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7031404

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951388/in-java-why-is-the-call-foo-not-ambigious-given-2-varags-methods-fooint-i

Comment: @Gary its not very similar :-) The question your refered (stackoverflow.com/questions/951388/) is according to spec i.e. explainable. This one appears to be a bug in JDK6 (fixed in JDK7?).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An intuitive way to test whether `method1` is more specific than `method2` is to see whether `method1` can be implemented by invoking `method2` with the same parameters

```
method1(params1){
    method2(params1);   // if compiles, method1 is more specific than method2
}
```

If there are varargs, we may need to expand a vararg so that 2 methods have same number of params.

Let's check the first two `method()`s in your example

```
<K> void method_a(K arg, Object... otherArgs) {
    method_b(arg, otherArgs);   //ok L1
}
<K> void method_b(Object arg, Object... otherArgs) { // extract 1 arg from vararg
    method_a(arg, otherArgs);   //ok L2
}
```

(return types are not used in determining specificity, so they are omitted)

Both compile, therefore each is more specific than the other, hence the ambiguity. Same goes for your `method2()`s, they are more specific than each other. Therefore the call to `method2()` is ambiguous and shouldn't compile; otherwise it's a compiler bug.

---

So that's what the spec says; but is it proper? Certainly, `method_a` looks more specific than `method_b`. Actually if we have a concrete type instead of `K`

```
void method_a(Integer arg, Object... otherArgs) {
    method_b(arg, otherArgs);   // ok
}
void method_b(Object arg, Object... otherArgs) {
    method_a(arg, otherArgs);   // error
}
```

then only `method_a` is more specific than `method_b`, not vice versa.

The discrepancy arises from the magic of type inference. `L1`/`L2` calls a generic method without explicit type arguments, so the compiler tries to infer the type arguments. The *goal* of type inference algorithm is to find type arguments *such that the code compiles*! No wonder L1 and L2 compile. L2 is actually infer to be `this.<Object>method_a(arg, otherArgs)`

Type inference tries to guess what the programmer wants, but the guess must be wrong sometimes. Our real intention is actually

```
<K> void method_a(K arg, Object... otherArgs) {
    this.<K>method_b(arg, otherArgs);   // ok
}
<K> void method_b(Object arg, Object... otherArgs) {
    this.<K>method_a(arg, otherArgs);   // error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the intuitive test.. but it doesn't answer the question. The question is why does the invocation of method **fail** but method2 **passes**.

Comment: from the analysis, call to `method2` is ambiguous for lack of *most specific* method. therefore it is a compiler bug.